# How do you terminate a ros spin when receiving a message

Tags: ros

We know the classic form of a subscriber node in ROS

```
def callback(msg):
    #do something with the msg

rospy.init_node('the_node',anonymous=True)
sub= rospy.Subscriber('message',Image, callback) # for example Images, but can be anything
rospy.spin()
```

Here the node will be receiving mesages and processing them with callback, while ROS "spins"

My question is, is there a simple way to get out of this spin based on for example a message we receive?

```
def callback(msg):
    #If we receive a msg that says "FINISH" break the main spin

rospy.init_node('the_node',anonymous=True)
sub= rospy.Subscriber('message',Image, callback) # for example Images, but can be anything
rospy.spin()
print("spin was broken")
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose `rospy.spin()` is to go into an infinite loop processing callbacks until a shutdown signal is received. The way to get out of the spin, and the only reason you ever should, is when the process is shutting down. This can be done via `sys.exit()` in python or `rospy.signal_shutdown()`.

Based on your example it seems like you want to break out of the spin but keep the node alive to do more work. If that's the case this is not the correct use of `rospy.spin()` and you should reconsider what you're trying to accomplish and by what method. Consider possibly using a run loop with `rospy.rate.sleep()`

```
cb_signal = False
def callback(msg):
    cb_signal = msg.data

def run():
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        #Do some other work
        if cb_signal == True:
            some_other_method()
        rospy.rate.sleep(10) #10Hz

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('my_node')
    rospy.Subscriber('message',Bool, callback)
    run()
```